# Предварительная загрузка WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk, мобильная-разработка

Задача состоит в том, чтобы скрыть от пользователя то, что он переместился на сайт, а соответственно при нажатии определенной кнопки, должна сразу отображаться уже загруженная и прошедшая все редиректы webview. Как передать в новую activity уже загруженный webview, созданный ранее?